# Differentiation operator in $\mathbb{k}[x]$ where $\text{char} (\mathbb{k})$ is prime

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $\mathbb{k}$ is a field of characteristic $p>0$. Consider the differentiation operator $D:\mathbb{k}[x]\to \mathbb{k}[x]$. Describe $\text{ker}(D)$ and $\text{Im}(D)$.

**My approach:** I was able to show that $$\ker(D)=\{\sum \limits_{k\leq n, \atop{p\mid k}}^{}a_kx^k: n\geq 0\}=\mathbb{k}[x^p].$$

And this answer coincides with the answer of my book. And the book says that the $\text{Im}(D)$ is consists of all polynomials of the form $\sum\limits_{p \nmid k} a_kx^k$. However, in my opinion this is not  correct answer because for example the polynomial $x^p$ is also in the image because $D(x^{p+1})=x^p$.

And I have spent some time and I was able to show that $$\text{Im}(D)=\{\sum \limits_{p\nmid k+1}a_kx^k\}.$$

Is this correct answer?

Would be very thankful for any comments!

Comment: Yes, both answers of yours are correct, and the book probably has a typo.

Comment: @WhatsUp, thanks a lot!